# Importing variable from a function of one script into separate script in Python

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import a variable which is created inside a function of one python script into another python script, but I am receiving an error.

Here is what I have tried:

```
# File1.py:
-----------
from file2 import foo
def myfunc():
    print(foo.x)

myfunc() #calling the function


# File2.py:
-----------
def foo():
    x=7
```

This is throwing an error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I am new to Python, can someone please help me on this to resolve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using global variable:

```
# File1.py:
-----------
from file2 import x
def myfunc():
    print(x)

myfunc() #calling the function


# File2.py:
-----------
def foo():
    global x
    x=7
```

This should work.